# integer to bool array

Tags: c++

I want to encode the integer like 83 to binary code like 1100101 what is the fastest way to do that? now I'm using this code:

```
ToBinary(int size, int value) {  
    size--;  
    this->code = new bool[size];  
    int in = size;  
    while (in >= 0) {  
        if(pow(2, in) <= value) {  
        this->code[size-in] = pow(2, in);  
        value -= pow(2, in);  
        } else   
            this->code[size-in] = 0;  
        in--;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: That's a rather awkward way to do it.  Simpler by far (and easier to understand) is to create a mask variable with 0x0001 in it and then shift that value one position at a time and AND with the input value.  Test the result of the AND to set your bool or not.

Comment: `for(int idx = 0; idx <= size; ++idx) { this->code[size - idx] = !!(value & (1 << idx)); }`

Comment: You can also use either `std::vector<bool>` or better `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`

Comment: thx guys, helped, i have a dumb question :D how to vote as Useful comment :D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of shifting using `>>` to make things a lot easier:

```
ToBinary(int size, int value) {
    int i = size;

    this->code = new bool[size];

    while(i--) {
        this->code[i] = (value >> i) & 1;
    }
}
```

(Or, to have it in the opposite order, `this->code[size - i]`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size at compile time, `std::bitset<size> bits(value);` will do what you want in its constructor.